# What's the logic behind some WriteStream messages?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Consider the following sequence of messages:

```
1. s := '' writeStream.
2. s nextPutAll: '123'.
3. s skip: -3.
4. s position "=> 0".
5. s size "=> 3".
6. s isEmpty "=> false".
7. s contents isEmpty "=> true (!)"
```

Aren't 6 and 7 contradictory or, at least, confusing? What's the logic behind this behavior? (Dolphin has a similar functioning.)

**UPDATE**

As @MartinW observed (see the comment below) `ReadStream` and `ReadWriteStream` behave differently (we could say, as expected.)

From a practical viewpoint the compatibility that worries me more is with `FileStream` where the `contents` message is not limited to the current `position.` Such a difference invalidates an otherwise nice "law" by which *any code that works with a memory stream (string or byte array) also works with a file stream, and conversely*. This kind of equivalence is very useful for testing and also for pedagogical reasons. The apparent loss of functionality would be easily recovered by adding the method `#truncate` to `WriteStream` which would explicitly shorten the `size` to the current `position` [cf., the discussion below with Derek Williams]

Comment: Yes, that's interesting. And it's only on `WriteStream`, where `contents` returns  `^collection copyFrom: 1 to: position`, on `ReadStream` or `ReadWriteStream` `contents` returns `^collection copyFrom: 1 to: readLimit`.

Answer (score 2):

In many Smalltalks (like VAST), the method comments explain it well:

```
WriteStream>>contents
   "Answer a Collection which is a copy collection that the receiver is
    streaming over, truncated to the current position reference."

PositionableStream>>isEmpty
   "Answer a Boolean which is true if the receiver can access any
    objects and false otherwise."
```

Note "*truncated to the current position reference*."

In your example, `contents` is an empty string because you set the position back to 0 with `skip: -3`.

This behavior is not only correct, it's quite useful.  For example, consider a method that builds a comma-separated list from a collection:

```
commaSeparatedListFor: aCollection 

    ws := '' writeStream.
    aCollection do: [ :ea |
       ws print: ea; nextPutAll: ', ' ].
    ws isEmpty
      ifFalse: [ ws position: ws position - 2 ].
    ^ws contents
```

In this case, the method may have written the final trailing ", ", but we want `contents` to exclude it.

Comment: Yes. Even when I can think a couple of better ways to avoid that comma, I find that can be useful sometimes.
But I find it of little worth compared to the confusion caused by having contents with different semantics on WriteStream and ReadWriteStream.

Comment: @Derek many thanks for the example. I find it interesting. However, isn't this use of the convention hiding a an actual truncation? You could have made the truncation explicit by saying `ws truncate contents`; which would have better revealed your intention.

Comment: Yes it is, and adding `truncate` is a good idea.  It's even been done in VAST (for ReadWriteStream) and perhaps other Smalltalks.  So in VAST you can do this: `|ws| ws := ReadWriteStream on: ''. ws nextPutAll: 'yo!'; position: ws position - 1; truncate; contents`.  If you comment out `truncate`, you get the exclamation point; otherwise it's, well, truncated.  Ambiguity about implied truncates on write streams and read/write streams is common in other places, too, (like OSes and C runtimes), and some added an explicit truncate call to clear that up. Perhaps Pharo should do the same.